# Change the color of the border of a text box in NSIS Graphical Installer

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to change the color of the border of a text box in NSIS.
This changes the background of the text box and of the font:

```
    SetCtlColors $varPageUserDetails.TextBoxEmail  0x48ffd5 0x0e2a47
```

This has no effect on the border of the text box (I tried lot's of options):

```
       ${NSD_AddExStyle} $varPageUserDetails.TextBoxEmail ${WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE}|${WS_EX_TRANSPARENT}
```

I tried Resource Hacker but didn't find any option to change the border color.

Is my only option is to write a windows application and use ChangeUI?

Comment: The transparent style cannot be used like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally can't change the border color of standard Windows controls. You can remove the border by not having WS_BORDER nor WS_EX_*EDGE.

ChangeUI cannot help you here, you would have to write a custom plug-in that subclasses the controls and draws the non-client area with your custom color.

There are some skinning plug-ins on the NSIS wiki you could also take a look at...

Comment: @Andres Thanks. This works for me. You can change the border color in cpp/c#. So why CnageUI won' help?

Comment: ChangeUI just changes the dialog resource layout/design but you always end up with plain Win32 controls.